# Does a command exist that lists all the directories where a word appears in a file or directory name?

Tags: linux, sort, uniq, locate, dirname

When I don't remember where a file or a folder is, I sometime use the `locate` command
(that finds more occurrences, allow more candidates than a `find`, in my mind. But maybe I'm mistaking).

But then there's a lot of responses, of course:

```bash
locate clang
```

```
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/Angular4/bikes/node_modules/blocking-proxy/.clang-format
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/Angular4/bikes/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/tools/Xcode/Specifications/gyp.xclangspec
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/Angular6/ng6-proj/node_modules/blocking-proxy/.clang-format
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/Angular6/ng6-proj/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/tools/Xcode/Specifications/gyp.xclangspec
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/blog-demo/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/tools/Xcode/Specifications/gyp.xclangspec
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/blog-demo/node_modules/blocking-proxy/.clang-format
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/blog-demo/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/tools/Xcode/Specifications/gyp.xclangspec
/data/sauvegardes/dev/Java/Experimentations/ol-ext-angular/.metadata/.plugins/ts.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.embed.win32.win32.x86_64/node-v6.9.4-win-x64/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/tools/Xcode/Specifications/gyp.xclangspec

(201 responses)
```

I piped this command, with `dirname`, `sort` and `uniq` to list only directories having such word in their name or carrying one or more file having it.

```bash
locate clang | xargs -L1 dirname | sort | uniq
```

it works...

```
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/AdapterInboundWebEtude/etude/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/tools/Xcode/Specifications
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/AdapterInboundWebEtude/etude/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/tools/Xcode/Specifications
/usr/include/boost/align/detail
/usr/include/boost/config/compiler
/usr/include/boost/predef/compiler
/usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts
/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/bitcode/postgres/commands
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/local/go/misc/ios
/usr/local/go/src/debug/dwarf/testdata
/usr/local/go/src/debug/elf/testdata
/usr/local/go/src/debug/macho/testdata
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libclang1-14
/usr/share/doc/libclang-cpp14

(108 responses)
```

But does *Linux* have a command doing the same, more easily?

Comment: What do you mean by "more easily"? You could put your pipeline in a shell function or script (taking the string, `clang`, as a command line argument) and that would be _shorter_, but I don't really know what you're looking for.

Comment: Linux is just a kernel, it doesn't have any command. Some Linux-based OSes such as Android, Debian or OpenWRT have commands but often different between themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if on a GNU system, you could use GNU `find`'s `-printf` which allows you to specify the output format. Sticking to `sort` is fine, as having separate commands for specific tasks somehow fulfils the KISS-concept. `sort` does have `-u`, though, so `uniq` may be omitted:

```
find . -name '*targetstring*' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
```

For handling newlines in directory names, a bit of extra effort would be necessary:

```
find . -name '*targetstring*' -printf '%h\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

(`LC_ALL=C` to also avoid issues with file paths not made of valid text  or containing characters that sort the same in the user's locale).

Replace `-name` with `-path` to look for `targetstring` anywhere in the path, not just the base name.

`-z` and `-printf` are GNU extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In the `zsh` shell

```
(){ print -rC1 -- ${(u)@}; } **/*clang*(ND:h)
```

Would `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn the `u`nique `h`eads (dirnames) of the files whose name contains `clang`.

Making that anonymous function a `printu` (for *print unique*) named one as:

```
printu() print -rC1 -- "${(u)@}"
```

Would allow you to write it:

```
printu **/*clang*(ND:h)
```

For the heads of files whose *path* (not just the base name) contains `clang`:

```
set -o extendedglob
printu **/*~^*clang*(ND:h)
```

(where `~` is a *except* extended operator and `^` a *not* extended operator).

Answer (score 0):

I know of nothing already existing that addresses your requirement. However, if you can compose a solution then it can be turned into a command (either a function or a script).

For example, this could go into your `.bashrc` or equivalent to define `dlocate`:

```
dlocate() {
    locate -0eb -- "$1" |
        while IFS= read -d '' -r x; do [ -d "$x" ] && printf '%s\n' "$x"; done
}
```

Or you could create a corresponding script and put it in one of the directories listed in your `$PATH` (I usually use `$HOME/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.)

Either way, this `dlocate` command searches for directories in the `locate` database that contain the supplied name fragment. For example, this would match any directory name containing `net`:

```
dlocate net
```

On my system this includes directories such as these,

```
/usr/include/net
/usr/share/doc/update-inetd
/usr/share/pixmaps/nethack
```

The `while` loop is required to exclude all non-directories, since `locate` returns all files and directories that match its filter. I've let it find symlinks to directories, but you could exclude those by extending `[ -d "$x" ]` to become `[ -d "$x" ] && [ ! -h "$x" ]` in the conditions chain.

Comment: Several `locate` implementations have `-b`/`--basename` to search in the base name only (using wildcards rather than regex by default; regexps are not ideal for file names given that `.` is a regex operator and common in file names) . Recent versions of GNU `find` can do `find -files0-from - -prune -type d` to select files of type *directory* from the NUL-delimited list on its stdin. Beware `[`'s `-d` also returns true for symlinks to directories.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you. I missed that one when checking the manpage for `mlocate`. Answer amended